# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Int64Index'

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

I have the latest version of pandas, 2.0.1.

This simple code:

```py
import pandas
pandas.Int64Index
```

Gives the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Int64Index'
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling pandas using `pip` and `conda`, also
restarted Jupyter notebook, but still getting the error.

Answer (score 5):

2.0.1 is a minor release after the major update to pandas 2.0 which removed old deprecated code such as `Int64Index`. From the 2.0 change log, [Index can now hold numpy numeric dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#index-can-now-hold-numpy-numeric-dtypes)

> Int64Index, UInt64Index & Float64Index were deprecated in pandas
> version 1.4 and have now been removed. Instead Index should be used
> directly, and can it now take all numpy numeric dtypes, i.e. int8/
> int16/int32/int64/uint8/uint16/uint32/uint64/float32/float64 dtypes

When something goes missing in a major release, always check the changelog.

The equivalent of `Int64Index` is (after importing numpy)

```
pd.Index([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the error just before I want to save the dataframe as a file. So my workaround to avoid the error:
Put the three lines of code just before you want to save the dataframe to a file. But save it to a file is optional ofcourse (thats why I put the # infront).

```
df["row_id"] = df.index + 1
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.set_index("row_id", inplace = True)
#df.to_file("C:\\...")
```

note that the indexcolumn is renamed to "row_id" and it starts counting at 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered occurs because Int64Index has been removed starting from version 1.4. Consequently, this issue arises if you are using a version of pandas newer than 1.4.

Ref: [What’s new in 2.0.0 (April 3, 2023)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html)

The solution is just to replace the

```
X["yourIndex"] = pd.Int64Index(X.index)
```

with

```
X["yourIndex"] = pd.Index(X.index)
```